# Best way for people to reference who is doing what?

Tags: sharepoint-online, collaboration, task-assignment

So I need some inspiration on how\what is the best way to achieve the following on SharePoint.

We have tasks assigned to individuals each weekend and we want an easy point of reference where by someone can go to the page\site and see who is doing what.

Would you use a calendar and just add these entries? Or is there something better?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use a **Task List**, e.g. within a project site.

[image]

For additional information, see [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-manage-a-project-task-list-466ad207-46fd-4c77-9af1-41bc23cec21a)

Answer (score 0):

I created an InfoPath form for the users to populate. The next task is to get that displayed correctly.

Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Office 365 user, you could go with Planner which shows all the tasks being worked on, on each "project"

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-all-of-your-tasks-and-plans-9c7a9c8e-b26e-451a-a49d-952132abe270